# Different leaderboards for different levels using Redis

Tags: python, django, redis

I'm new to Redis, and I'm trying to create leaderboards for different levels in a game (e.g. the game might have 20 levels, and I would like to create 20 different leaderboards).

Reading the documentation from AWS, it seems that sorted sets are the way to go, but would I need to create 20 different elastic cache instances?

Or would I do something like ZADD leaderboard:1, ZADD:leaderboard:2, where 1 or 2 corresponds to the id of the game?

Apologies if this is a stupid question as this is my first attempt at Redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create 20 different ElastiCache instances, you may just use one(you need to decide the instance type depending on size, network etc).

Whenever you need to add a new user to a level(update the score if he exists), you need to execute `zadd` with the key of the level, the user and the score(points in your domain). zadd also supports setting multiple user scores at once.

```
> ZADD leaderboard:1 154 "user273"
(integer) 1
> ZADD leaderboard:2 12 "user786"
(integer) 1
> ZADD leaderboard:3 221 "user:6817" 912 "user:21233"
(integer) 2
```

When `user:123` entered to the leaderboard with the score of `15` and then he gets `19`, his score(points) will be overwritten when you execute `zadd`.

You will have a sorted set with full of unique users with their corresponding scores. The tricky parts in here; If you are going to get the top 5 users then you need to use `zrevrange` instead of `zrange` because your rank will be smaller(numeric order) when your points are higher. In that case

> `zrevrange leaderboard:1 0 4 withscores`

will give you the top 5 users at level 1. `withscores` is optional.

Comment: Thank you, and I'll do that.